# How to fix Exec Error when compiling for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an app that has previously compiled successfully in Delphi Berlin for **Windows 32 + 64** and Android, but when I edited it today, it will not compile for Android anymore.

Below is the compiler error, which contains several paths that do not exist.  In particular, it has residue from a newer Delphi version that was a trial which I installed and later uninstalled.  I found a file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Path-After-Install.txt`) that contains an exact copy of the error string, but editing that does nothing.

Can somebody tell me how to get this working again?

```
[Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;

    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Interbase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin;
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin64;
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bpl\Win64;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin;
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin64;
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\Win64;
    C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
    C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile64\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector64\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
    C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;
    C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;
    C:\Users\lorne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
     & "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\29.0.3\dx.bat" --dex --output="D:\Lorne\Documents\Borland\ConverterFMX\Android\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-services.dex.jar" " exited with code 3.
```

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\29.0.3` actually exist? Exit code 3 usually means Windows is attempting to open/read something that does not exist

Comment: It seems that installing newer version of Delphi might have screwed Android SDK's. Removing support for Android platform through Delphi platform manager, restarting computer and then adding Android platform again through Delphi's platform manager might force Delphi to reinstall all the missing components to working with Android platform. I managed to restore Android SDK's in the past this way.

Comment: I went to the SDK Manager and found all the paths led to the C: drive whereas all the files were on the D: drive but in the same folder trees so almost certain that installing a later trial version of delphi put the android files on a different drive causing the issue. However After changing C to D all the folders were found but I now get the error:  'arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl' but that file exists in the location it says it is looking but I am not sure what -ldl means. Are there other files I need that are missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I did finally solve this by uninstalling and then reinstalling Android, but it took 2 goes.  Second time I went through the registry and disk drive to remove all references to Android that were linked to RAD Studio before the reinstall.